# Tex for Mathematical Operator which Looks Like a Y

Tags: fonts, math-mode, symbols

Does anybody know what the correct latex is for the character which looks like a Y in this equation?

[image: equation]

I've sometimes seen it used for the Euler homogeneity operator too.

I can't seem to produce it from any of the standard math fonts, nor can I find it in the Hebrew or Russian alphabets! Any thoughts would be great!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a Greek letter `\Upsilon`.

Comment: Thanks - that's great. Just looking in the wrong alphabets I guess!

Comment: When in doubt, it's Greek.  Hebrew and Russian letters have very rare occurrences in math.

Comment: Aleph is not of very rare occurrence ;-)

Comment: Well, it occurs in exactly one way, and aside from Bet (which is much less common and occurs in the same way), it's the only Hebrew letter to do so.  And the only Russian letter I know of is Sha; I suppose arithmetic geometers would say that's important, but in both cases, I maintain that you basically have to know you're looking at these letters if you see them.

Comment: Maybe I should say: use of non-Greek letters in math is considered idiosyncratic.

Comment: I'd like to add that this is a *mathematical* capital upsilon. The regular capital upsilon looks exactly like the capital Y (which is why the mathematical capital upsilon is written this way). People familiar with the Greek alphabet (but unfamiliar with this mathematical variant) would probably try to find it in a different alphabet.

Comment: @Silex Interesting.  I wonder why there aren't mathematical variants of all the capital Greek letters.  Alpha in particular would be appreciated, and capitals beta (= B) and zeta (= Z) actually get used, absurdly.